# Module not found on the new React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, module

I have upgraded my react but now I only fix the errors, this is the only thing I do ,but I don't know what to do with these ones..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llre3.png)

I tried install the packages but still got these error..

Comment: please checkout the standard practice of how to write a question on stack overflow, with the information you have presented is not enough for anyone to find the solution , cheers.

Comment: yes ok , I will make another post and try to provide more information. Sorry , but this is my second question here on StackOverflow ... I will improve ...:)